# AngularJS ng-include function or value binding per property

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I would like to do the following:

`ng-style="{ 'width': iconWidth(), 'height': height }"`

`iconWidth` being a function and `height` being a string. I would like to keep the ng-style syntax and not bind the ng-style to an entire object (not `ng-style="css"`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, do it, and ask a question if there is something wrong.

Comment: Your syntax seems good. Please add a plunker to your question

Comment: Seems all right, what is your request exactly?

Comment: My problem is that if I use a function the binding is not applied.

Comment: `ng-style="{ 'width' : iconStyle.iconWidth() }"` does not work for me.

Comment: Does the function have a "return" value? Why don't you do the operation in your controller and then pass to the scope the returned value?

I.E. 

`var iconWidth = function(){
   // your operation here
   return iconW;
};

$scope.[your variables name here] = iconWidth;`

and then 

`ng-style="{ 'width' : [your variables name here] }"`

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or a jsfiddle of your code please?

Comment: @Linvi try this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TTBhwCqioKEELAGfkrwl?p=preview) look for `div` with `p` tag saying `Solution to your CSS problem`

Comment: Hello all, I am working on a plunker. With a simple plunker everything worked as expected, yet the same code is not working outside of plunker, I am working on repro case.

Comment: After further investigation it was a problem with the digest synchronization. Sorry for the inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by fixing a digest synchronization problem.